# How can I synchronize an object in Mirror

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm doing a multiplayer project in **unity3d**
using `"MIRROR"` and the player's body turns up and down as in Rust, Tarkov, DayZ.
And during the multiplayer session, the body is not synchronized, the player simply turns, without moving the body up, down. Tried `[Command]`, `[Client]`, `[ClientRpc]`, `[TargetRpc]`
But nothing helped.